# Azure Notification Hub installationId - when to re-generate?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

We are using the Installation model to manage our push notifications.

My question is simple: when should we re-generate the `installationId`?

a) For a new install of an app

b) For a new install of an app *or* an update?

We are having some issues *updating templates* for an existing `installationId`, so wondering if we should be doing option b)?

What exactly is the intended lifetime of an `installationId`?

**EDIT**

The issue we are seeing is as follows:

1. User installs a version of an app which uses push notification template xyz, registers with Azure NH. New `installationId` is generated.
2. User receives push notifications, all good.
3. User installs an *update* of the app version, registration happens with Azure NH with *updated* template but *same* `installationId`.
4. User receives push notification for *old* template

In other words - it doesn't appear the templates are being *updated* when the installationId is the same.

**EDIT 2**

Here are some repro steps. App is an iPhone app, which communicates to a .NET backend to register for push notifications. .NET backend talks to Azure NH. (`Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs` v1.0.7). Backend is using *installation* model (e.g `CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync`, taking in an `installationId` generated by app, as well as a bunch of templates/tags).

Repro steps:

- Deleted the app
- Installed app from app store (old template)
- Opened the app, tested push and it worked fine (uses expected template)
- Downloaded latest version of app (new templates)
- Opened the app, app calls .NET backend to `CreateOrUpdateInstallation` with new templates
- Tested push and got the old template. (wrong)
- opened and closed the app several times to force new updated but was still getting the old template.

Comment: @Mimi Xu hoping you can help me with this.

Comment: There should be a 1:1 mapping between `installationId` and device token. Meaning that you shouldn't have to regenerate `installationId`s at all. What kind of issues are you having? (If you suspect it's a bug on the server side, could you mention your namespace and approximate time-frame when it happened?)

Comment: @NikitaG. - updated question with more info. namespace is `homely-notificationhub`. has happened in last 24 hours.

Comment: As Nikita said, there is no need to change installation ids for various installs as long as there is one unique install of the app on the device. If you suspect that installations are not getting updated properly, we'd love more info! If you don't mind sharing the repro steps and the sdk/apis you are working with, our team can take a closer look.

Comment: @rpm1984, one important thing to make sure first is that [registrations are not confused with installations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management/). (In your question you mention installationId  along with 'registration happens'.) Also, can you consistently repro the scenario? It's possible that if you do a template update and then immediately do a push the new template still is being updated, so the old one is used. But usually within seconds it should get processed.

Comment: @MimiXu and @Nikita G thanks for jumping in on this. I edited with more info, and repro steps. We are using the `installation` model, not the `registration` model. We can't consistently reproduce, but it's not time based/delay in updating templates - i say that because when it doesnt work for a device, it will never work until the installation is re-created with a new installationId. (which should never need to be done)

Comment: Can you share a few tracking ids of CreateOrUpdate and Send operations, and times when you received them?

Comment: @DmitryP. not sure what a "tracking id" is? Do you mean `installationId`?

Answer (score 0):

When you updated the app, 
New templates are used with same Installation ID. Then you are using createOrUpdateInstallation(), though the name has 'update' in it, NotificationHub documentation advises us to use PatchInstallationAsync() with patch-update process. [PatchInstallationAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.patchinstallationasync?view=azure-dotnet)